# Почему ArrayList.add() работает не так, как я этого ожидаю?

Tags: java

У меня есть следующий код на языке Java:

```js
package task;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Loops implements GeneralLoops{
    
    ...
  
    private ArrayList<Integer> currentStatus = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<List<Integer>> statusList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    
    ...
    
    private void iterate(int index) {
        for(int i = lowerLimits.get(index); i <= upperLimits.get(index); i++) {
            currentStatus.set(index, i);
            if(index < size-1)
                iterate(index+1);
            else {
                statusList.add(currentStatus);
                System.out.println(currentStatus);
            }
        }
        currentStatus.set(index, lowerLimits.get(index));
    }
    
  ...
  
    public List<List<Integer>> getResult() {
        iterate(0);
        return statusList;
    }
    
  ...
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Loops loop = new Loops();
        
    ...
    
        List<List<Integer>> result = loop.getResult();
        
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Метод `getResult` должен имитировать работу вложенных циклов и возвращать состояния итераторов на каждой итерации. Суть в том, что сам алгоритм реализован правильно, а вот запись в список `statusList` почему-то работает не так, как бы этого хотелось. Строчка `System.out.println(currentStatus)` выписывает каждое состояние правильно, но при добавлении этого состояния statusList он заменяется на `{0, 0, 1}`, в следствии чего последняя строка вывода выглядит примерно так: `[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], ..., [0, 0, 1]]`. Подскажите, почему метод `add` некорректно добавляет элемент в список? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> почему метод add некорректно добавляет элемент в список

Метод `add` все делает правильно. Это Вы неправильно им пользуетесь. Вы все время добавляете ссылку на один и тот же объект - список, содержимое которого постоянно меняете. Поэтому все элементы `statusList` ссылаются на один список.

Comment: можете подсказать, как правильно добавить элемент в `statusList`?

Comment: а, все, я сам понял, в чем была проблема. Спасибо большое за помощь!